# $K(x)\cong K(x,y)$ as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $K$ be a field, and $K(x), K(x,y)$ be rational function fields.

Now, $K(x)\ncong K(x,y)$ as fields (**not** as $K$ isomorphism)?

By  transcendence degree, these are not $K$ isomorphism, but I do not know how it is field isomorphism.

More generally, if $K(x_1,\dots,x_n)\cong K(y_1,\dots,y_m)$, then $n=m$?

Help me thanks.

Comment: They *could* be: if $K=\mathbb{C}(T)$ where $T$ is an infinite set of transcendental variables, then $K(x)$ and $K(x,y)$ are both purely transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{C}$ of transcendental degree $|T|$, hence isomorphic. On the other hand, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ are not isomorphic, since any isomorphism is a $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism, and they have different transcendence degree.

Comment: Thanks, is it hard we get equivalence condition about field $K$?

Comment: Isomorphism of fields is the same as isomorphism of $F$-extensions, where $F$ is the prime field of $K$. The transcendence degree of $K(x),K(x,y)$ over $F$ is respectively $1$ or $2$ greater than the transcendence degree of $K$ over $F$, so if the latter is finite, these cannot be isomorphic as fields.